# Glassfish Logging Custom Pattern

Tags: logging, glassfish, slf4j, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

I would like to print some MDC values in Glassfish, but I can't find where to change the logging pattern.

This is what I have in my code:

```
MDC.put("something", "SOME_VALUE");
```

But then I need to configure somewhere the pattern like this:

```
%-4r [%thread] %-5level %X{something} - %msg%n
```

**So my simple question is: where should I put that in Glassfish?**

I am using:

- Glassfish 4.1
- slf4j

Comment: Hi @Pablo, did you get this working? I am working on an application that uses `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter`. I am trying to make use of MDC to log some custom headers.Can change to SimpleFormatter, but checking if we can make this work with exiting Formatter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the logging output in `<glassfish-install-dir>/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties` file.

To format your output you can use the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`.

Your logging.properties might look like this

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%-4r [%thread] %-5level %X{something} - %msg%n
```